# Require or import javascript module from Buffer

Tags: node.js, file, module

I have a .zip file with some javascript files in it.  I'd like to require those files and execute them as normal modules, but they're not actual files on the filesystem.  I can get a buffer representing the data inside those files, and I'd like to be able to just "require" them without writing them out to the filesystem just to read them in again.  I figure I could do some sneaky stuff with eval, but I'm thinking there's probably something more above-the-table.

The solution I have now writes the files out and requires them normally but there's complexities around idempotency and filesystem management that I'd really like to avoid by just "reading" from memory.  Also, the solution has to be portable across consumer operating systems.

I have control over the way the target javascript files export their contents, but I'd like to stick as closely as possible to idiomatic javascript.  If restricting how users export code to just one syntax type (ex just "module.exports = 'foo'" or just "export default function foo () {}") makes this simpler its on the table.

Comment: Looks like the package https://github.com/node-eval/node-eval will do the shady eval stuff for me, but I'm still looking for a more straightforward approach.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?